# Loading controls inside a tab page in a tab control in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to load a form inside a tab page in a tab control in C# ?

Comment: dynamically or design time?

Comment: @Frebin Francis : dynamically

Comment: use this link sorry it's in vb.net you have to convert it to c#  http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/515603-load-form-tab-control-page also this one http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/367314/Form-as-Tab

Comment: can i post it as an answer?

Comment: @Frebin Francis : yeah sure.. you can post your answer thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My code is in vb.net language you need to convert it into c#.

Assuming you have two forms: 
1) MainForm - form that contains the tabcontrol (assuming it has 2 pages)
2) UserForm - form to be added into the MainForm's tabcontrol page.

There are two solutions:

**1 Solution: In the load event of MainForm write this code...**

```
Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  Dim frmUser As New UserForm
  frmUser.TopLevel = False
  frmUser.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle

  Me.TabControl1.TabPages(0).Controls.Add(frmUser)
  frmUser.Show()

End Sub
```

Note: you may change the borderstyle to suit your preferences. You may set it to "NONE" so that the controls in UserForm will appear like part of the tab page control and not the Form itself.

**2 Solution**

Create UserForm as a "user control" and not a "form" then rebuild. Once it is found in the object list in the Object Explorer, you can drag the object towards the tabpage on your MainForm.

You can also try [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/367314/Form-as-Tab)

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry i can't since i dont have sufficient reputation for upvoting an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can add to ControlCollection whatever instance extending from Control class. So, yes, it's possible.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

These could be possible solutions:

```
FormChild frmChild = new FormChild();
AddNewTab(frmChild);

private void AddNewTab(Form frm)
{

    TabPage tab = new TabPage(frm.Text);

    frm.TopLevel = false;

    frm.Parent = tab;

    frm.Visible = true;

    tabControl.TabPages.Add(tab);

    frm.Location = new Point((tab.Width - frm.Width) / 2, (tab.Height - frm.Height) / 2);

    tabControl.SelectedTab = tab;

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: this worked ,instead of giving location i gave frm.Dock== DockStyle.Fill so that the form got filled inside the tabpage..and it looks perfect..thankyou @Dave

Comment: Awesome! Good luck with the rest!

Answer (score 0):

The requirement was to load a form inside a tab page..and the tab control contains more than one tab page so i wrote the code inside the SelectedPageChanged event..and got it correctly..this is the code i tried

private void xtraTabControl1_SelectedPageChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTab.TabPageChangedEventArgs e){

```
        XtraForm2 mForm2 = new XtraForm2();

        mForm2.TopLevel = false;

        mForm2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

        mForm2.Parent = this.xtraTabPage2;

        mForm2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        mForm2.Show();
    }
```